# How to add SUM columns to a SQL query that are totaled by week when there is only one date column in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, sql-order-by, pivot

I'm writing a query to break down quantity of parts that have been ordered over a given year week by week.  The Parts Order Table however only has 1 date column in it.

Here is what I am trying to accomplish:

```
PartNo    PartDesc    Type       Week1    Week2    Week3 ...
------------------------------------------------------------
000001    Shoe        Black         54       44       6
000001    Shoe        White         64       33       7
000002    GLove       Black          1       22       8
000002    Glove       White          7       11       9
```

Here is the table layout

```
PartsOrderTable
----------------
PartNo
PartDesc
PartType
Qty
DateField
```

Here is my query so far, it work's great for week1, Im not sure how to append the other weeks to the end of the results?

```
SELECT PartNo, PartDesc, Type, SUM(Qty) as Week1 
FROM PartsOrderTable
WHERE DateField >= '1/1/2013'
AND DateField <= '12/31/2013'
And DATEPART(ww, DateField) = 1
GROUP BY PartNo, PartDesc, Type, DATEPART(ww, DateField)
ORDER BY PartNo, Week1
```

This is what I get back currently:

```
PartNo    PartDesc    Type       Week1
----------------------------------------
000001    Shoe        Black         54
000001    Shoe        White         64
000002    GLove       Black          1
000002    Glove       White          7
```

Is it possible in a simple query to tack on the quantity ordered by each week?

Comment: A normal query would return a row for each part/type/week combination (for example, add the `DATEPART` calc to your `SELECT` clause and remove it from the `WHERE` clause). Is it possible to do this and then transpose in the app/presentation tier? You can certainly do this with T-SQL but it's going to be extremely messy because you have to handle all 53-54 weeks individually. Your current query, by the way, doesn't need the `DATEPART` in the `GROUP BY`, at least I don't think. Do you get a different answer if you remove it?

Comment: @AaronBertrand - Yes I think you are correct in not needing the group by.  Left over tinkering there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `PIVOT` function to perform this so the code will be similar to the following:

```
select *
from
(
  SELECT PartNo, PartDesc, Type, Qty,
    'Week'+cast(DATEPART(ww, DateField) as varchar(2)) WeekNo
  FROM PartsOrderTable
  WHERE year(DateField) = 2013
) d
pivot
(
  sum(qty)
  for WeekNo in (Week1, Week2, Week3, Week4)
) piv
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e39c5/2).

If you had an unknown number of columns, or wanted to pass in a date range, then you could use dynamic sql to create the result. I *strongly urge* you to restrict the number of columns when returning dates dynamically,  you want to be sure that you are not returning too many columns:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME('Week'+cast(DATEPART(ww, DateField) as varchar(2))) 
                    from PartsOrderTable
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT PartNo, PartDesc, Type,' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
                SELECT PartNo, PartDesc, Type, Qty,
                  ''Week''+cast(DATEPART(ww, DateField) as varchar(2)) WeekNo
                FROM PartsOrderTable
                WHERE year(DateField) = 2013
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum(qty)
                for WeekNo in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e39c5/4)

Comment: +1 You could build this in dynamic SQL and then use a set to construct the `week1, week2, ...` etc. But still, yuck.

Comment: @AaronBertrand A dynamic version is yuck, but I added an example. If I were using this, I would make sure I passed in a date range so I didn't get too many columns.

Comment: Yeah OP seems to want the whole year. Which will be more than 52 columns depending on how weeks are measured.

Comment: @bluefeet - I think this may work.  It would be run only for one fiscal year at a time, so it would never be more than 52 columns.  Let me play with this and see if I can get it to work, Ill add another comment with my findings.

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur Either version should work. The first one you will have to type of all 52 weeks in the year. If you don't want to type 52 columns, then you can use a numbers table along with the dynamic sql to generate the 52 columns -- see this demo -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7c4c0/1

Comment: @bluefeet - Thank you very much this absolutely helped.  Is there a way I can use the `ISNULL` function with the pivot?  So if the `SUM` is NULL I can put a zero in there?  I tried a few ways but it wasnt happy with it.

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur On the dynamic version? Yes, you create a new set of columns to be created, you will use one for the pivot clause and the other for the select list -- see this demo  -http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7c4c0/2

Comment: I actually used the non-dynamic version, but that gives me a head start.

Comment: @ProfessionalAmateur Non-dynamic version the replacement takes place in the final select -- http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e39c5/5